# C# async wait for Task<T> to process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I make a httpclient postasync and I want to convert the response to my model object. This is my code:

```
var response = client.PostAsync(TERMBASED_ENDPOINT,
    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(),
                      Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>();
//other code synchronously processed
```

So, this code is asynchronously processed. What is the best method to wait for the response to be processed and just after this happens to continue to run the synchronous code??

Thank you!

Comment: does the other code work with `result`? if so you should be able to use it "right away" with the async/await magic!

Comment: Why are you calling the `PostAsync` method synchronously?

Comment: Is there some reason you're using `.Result` on `PostAsync()` instead of using `await`?  Aside from that, it's not really clear what the problem is here.  In what way is this code not working as expected?  When you `await` the result of an operation, it blocks that code until the result is available.

Answer (score 2):

"await" your post call to unwrap the response.

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(TERMBASED_ENDPOINT,
    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(),
                      Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response.Content);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are wanting to do is store the Task in a variable, do some work, and then await the response.

```
var response = client.PostAsync(TERMBASED_ENDPOINT,
    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(),
                      Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

var readTask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>();
//other code synchronously processed
var result = await readTask;
```

Alternatively, if you have several asynchronous tasks you can wait for them all and then process the results.

```
var response = client.PostAsync(TERMBASED_ENDPOINT,
    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(),
                      Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

var readTask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>();
//other code synchronously processed
await Task.WhenAll(readTask);
var result = readTask.Result;
```